# I tried to run bitcoin core and it is gone. Has anyone experienced this?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I tried to run bitcoin core and it is gone.The folder is still there, but the exe is not there. Does that mean the local wallet is gone as well?

Comment: Update: I found my data, but why would the exe disappear?

Comment: Please add updates by editing the question, not adding answers.

Answer (score 2):

Some antivirus programs can remove binaries, or move them away. If you have one running, look whether it has some kind of quarantine place where it puts suspected malware. False positives can happen.
That, or you deleted the file by mistake :)